# Accessing the Grafana.ini file in an Azure Managed Grafana instance

Tags: azure, grafana, monitoring

I'm wondering if it's possible to access the grafana.ini file in an Azure-managed instance of Grafana. The reason for this is that I need to modify a query timeout parameter, but I'm unable to locate where I can access that file in the Azure portal or within the Grafana UI.

We've tried accessing the ini file via the Azure portal and Grafana UI without luck.